# Could not find Chrome (ver. 121.0.6167.85). This can occur if either (on Render.com)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, server-side-rendering

I use `nodejs` and `puppeteer` and run normally on localhost, however when I deploy the api on `render.com` I get an error

```
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 121.0.6167.85). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /opt/render/project/src/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:285:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:196:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:89:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:70:28)
    at async getListNewNovel (/opt/render/project/src/controller/listController:8:29)
::1 - - [12/Feb/2024:04:26:48 +0000] "GET /v1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 39
```

My code:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const listController = {
    getListNewNovel: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
              });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(url);

            await autoScroll(page);

            const listDataTeam = await page.evaluate(() => {
                const dataList = [];
                

                return dataList;
            });

            await browser.close();
            res.status(200).json(listDataTeam);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error: " + error.name });
        }
    },

    
}

async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let totalHeight = 0;
            const distance = 100;
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    });
}


module.exports = listController;
```

Comment: Did you try running the command in the error message?